# VueJS: Is it suitable to trigger async function inside computed property?

Tags: vue.js, async-await, computed-properties

Use case: Automatically and lazy load data via Ajax from API if an reactive property is used.

The code already works as intended, but violates the best practice from the documentation, not to make async requests within computed properties:
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#best-practices

An alternative would be to call `loadTitle()` manually in `onMounted`. Triggering it within the computed property works better for me, because using a property is usually the best indication, it should be loaded.

I don't want to use "vue-async-computed". Synchronous computed properties fulfill the job. It is just about the side effect to trigger the `loadTitle()` function. Can anyone recommend this pattern or knows a better alternative?

```js
// "_title" is private.
const _title = ref('')

// "title" can be used in a template.
const title = computed(() => {
    if (_title.value === '') {
        loadTitle() // no await, just trigger ajax call.
    }

    // initially returns '' but changes to result of axios call,
    // as soon as it is set by loadTitle().
    return _title.value
})

let waiting = false
const loadTitle = async () => {
    if (waiting) {
        return
    }
    waiting = true
    _title.value = (await axios.get(url)).data
    waiting = false
}
```

Thanks in advance! The real world example is obviously more complex.

Comment: I came here wondering about the same. To me, a side effect in a computed property is the best way to trigger lazy loading, because it can determine that it is required.


For larger applications, I would emit a vue event or other event bus for context and DX that in turn triggers the call.


Have you found a better solution since?

Comment: @Goatfryed No silver bullet yet. Moved the state to pinia. Triggering the requests sometimes in `onMounted()` and sometimes like in this example. If a better solution shows up, I assume it will be a pinia plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's best to avoid an async call in a computed property.

What I have done in similar situations is have a computed property that depends on a certain value, then update that value when the data is loaded. I would have something like this in my `setup` function:

```js
const title = computed(() => {
  if (!asyncData) {
    return ""
  }
  return asyncData.title
})
```

The exact way that you update the `asyncData` would depend on how your app is set up. In my case I was using vue with apollo-composable so I used an `onResult` function to update the async data after it loaded. The same thing could be achieved by watching the result of the async call to manually update `asyncData`, which would cause the title to recompute.

Comment: Shorter version using ES6: `const title = computed(() => asyncData?.title || "")`